# How to get total count of each group concat fields?

Tags: mysql

I have one table called `'activity_data'`

table contain following fields

```
id int(11),
sports_name varchar(20),
activity_date datetime
```

information of `activity_data` table

```
id         sports_name      activity_date
1          Cricket          2015-05-12
2          Football         2015-05-12 
3          Cricket          2015-06-10    
4          Basketball       2015-06-08  
5          Khokho           2015-06-02 
6          Kubbdi           2015-06-04
7          Cricket          2015-05-12
8          Kubbdi           2015-05-12  
9          Cricket          2015-06-09   
10         Football         2015-06-03
```

now I'm execute following queries

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) id ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(sports_name)) sports_name,activity_date FROM filter_activity_data WHERE activity_date BETWEEN '2015-05-12' AND '2015-06-04' GROUP BY activity_date ORDER BY activity_date ASC
```

while executing this:output is getting like this

```
id         sports_name                activity_date
1,2,7,8    Cricket,Football,Kubbdi    2015-05-12
5          Khokho                     2015-06-02 
10         Football                   2015-06-03    
6          Kubbdi                     2015-06-04
```

I want to get output total count of each `GROUP_CONCAT sports_name`. expected out put like this:

```
id         sports_name                activity_date
2,1,1      Cricket,Football,Kubbdi    2015-05-12
1          Khokho                     2015-06-02 
1          Football                   2015-06-03    
1          Kubbdi                     2015-06-04
```

How to achieve this goal ?

Comment: you could try a derived query

Comment: i had tried also but not getting accurate data, please if you having any idea to resolved this things ?

Comment: If its just count for each sports name as `group_concat` then the date is redundant since cricket is also present on `2015-06-09`

Answer (score 3):

Hey used following query it might help you

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(t.name1) as name2 , GROUP_CONCAT(t.count) as counts , t.activity_date from 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) id ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(sports_name)) as name1 , count(*) as count , sports_name,activity_date FROM activity_data WHERE activity_date BETWEEN '2015-05-12' AND '2015-06-04' GROUP BY activity_date, sports_name ORDER BY activity_date ASC) as t 
group by t.activity_date
```

this query gives you exact result.

Comment: thank you vishal working fine,changing only one thing `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(t.count))` to  `GROUP_CONCAT(t.count)`